# Reverse order of dot-delimited elements in a string

Tags: shell, text-processing

I have an input string like:

```
arg1.arg2.arg3.arg4.arg5
```

The output I want is:

```
arg5.arg4.arg3.arg2.arg1
```

It's not always 5 arg's, could be 2 to 10.

How can I do this in a bash script?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

- Using combination of `tr`+`tac`+`paste`

  ```
  $ tr '.' $'\n' <<< 'arg1.arg2.arg3.arg4.arg5' | tac | paste -s -d '.'
  arg5.arg4.arg3.arg2.arg1
  ```
- If you still prefer bash, you could do in this way,

  ```
  IFS=. read -ra line <<< "arg1.arg2.arg3.arg4."
  let x=${#line[@]}-1; 
  while [ "$x" -ge 0 ]; do 
        echo -n "${line[$x]}."; 
        let x--; 
  done
  ```
- Using `perl`,

  ```
  $ echo 'arg1.arg2.arg3.arg4.arg5' | perl -lne 'print join ".", reverse split/\./;'
  arg5.arg4.arg3.arg2.arg1
  ```

Comment: Bah, I was just going to post the Perl solution :)

Answer (score 10):

If you do not mind a tiny bit of `python`:

```
".".join(s.split(".")[::-1])
```

**Example:**

```
$ python3 -c 's="arg1.arg2.arg3.arg4.arg5"; print(".".join(s.split(".")[::-1]))'
arg5.arg4.arg3.arg2.arg1
```

- `s.split(".")` generates a list containing `.` separated substrings, `[::-1]` reverses the list and `".".join()` joins the components of the reversed list with `.`.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with a single `sed` invocation:

```
sed -E 'H;g;:t;s/(.*)(\n)(.*)(\.)(.*)/\1\4\5\2\3/;tt;s/\.(.*)\n/\1./'
```

this uses the hold buffer to get a leading newline in the pattern space and uses it to do permutations until the newline is no longer followed by any dot at which point it removes the leading dot from the pattern space and replaces the newline with a dot.
With BRE and a slightly different regex:

```
sed 'H
g
:t
s/\(.*\)\(\n\)\(.*\)\(\.\)\(.*\)/\1\4\5\2\3/
tt
s/\(\.\)\(.*\)\n/\2\1/'
```

If the input consists of more than one line and you want to reverse the order on each line:

```
sed -E 'G;:t;s/(.*)(\.)(.*)(\n)(.*)/\1\4\5\2\3/;tt;s/(.*)\n(\.)(.*)/\3\2\1/'
```

Answer (score 4):

Didn't see an `awk` answer, so here's one:

```
 echo 'arg1.arg2.arg3' | awk -F. '{for (i=NF; i>0; --i) printf "%s%s", (i<NF ? "." : ""), $i; printf "\n"}'
```

Answer (score 3):

SED solution:

```
sed 's/\./\n/g' yourFile | tac | sed ':a; $!{N;ba};s/\n/./g'
```

Answer (score 3):

With  `zsh`:

```
$ string=arg1.arg2.arg3.arg4.arg5
$ printf '%s\n' ${(j:.:)${(Oas:.:)string}}
arg5.arg4.arg3.arg2.arg1
```

To preserve empty elements:

```
$ string=arg1.arg2.arg3.arg4..arg5.
$ printf '%s\n' ${(j:.:)"${(@Oas:.:)string}"}
.arg5..arg4.arg3.arg2.arg1
```

- `s:.:`: split on `.`
- `Oa`: sort array in reverse **a**rray indice **o**rder
- `j:.:`: join on `.`.
- `@`: do `"$@"`-like expansion when in double quotes so the expansion doesn't undergo empty-removal.

The POSIX (or `bash`) equivalent could be something like:

```
string=arg1.arg2.arg3.arg4..arg5.

IFS=.; set -f
set -- $string$IFS # split string into "$@" array
unset pass
for i do # reverse "$@" array
  set -- "$i" ${pass+"$@"}
  pass=1
done
printf '%s\n' "$*" # "$*" to join the array elements with the first
                   # character of $IFS
```

(note that `zsh` (in `sh` emulation), `yash` and some `pdksh`-based shells are not POSIX in that regard in that they treat `$IFS` as a field separator instead of field delimiter)

Where it differs from some of the other solutions given here is that it doesn't treat the newline character (and in the case of `zsh`, the NUL one either) specially, that is `$'ab.cd\nef.gh'` would be reversed to `$'gh.cd\nef.ab'`, not `$'cd.ab\ngh.ef'` or `$'gh.ef.cd.ab'`.

Comment: Whats wrong with `IFS="."; set -f; set -- $string$IFS; for i; do rev="$i$IFS$rev"; done; printf '%s\n' "${rev%$IFS}"`?

Comment: @BinaryZebra Nothing (apart maybe from the `for i; do` which is not POSIX (yet) even if it's supported by all the POSIX shells that I know). It's just that that solution is a direct translation of the `zsh` one (split into array, reverse array, join array elements) but using POSIX-only operators. (I've changed the `string=$string$IFS; set -- $string` to `set -- $string$IFS` as that seems to work consistently across shells, thanks).

Answer (score 2):

I see Rahul already [posted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/302292/117549) a native bash solution (among others), which is a shorter version of the first one I came up with:

```
function reversedots1() (
  IFS=. read -a array <<<"$1"
  new=${array[-1]}
  for((i=${#array[*]} - 2; i >= 0; i--))
  do
    new=${new}.${array[i]}
  done
  printf '%s\n' "$new"
)
```

but I couldn't stop there, and felt the need to write a recursive bash-centric solution:

```
function reversedots2() {
  if [[ $1 =~ ^([^.]*)\.(.*)$ ]]
  then
    printf %s $(reversedots2 "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}") . "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  else
    printf %s "$1"
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pure Bash, requires trailing period on input:

```
echo 'foo.bar.baz.' | ( while read -d . f;do g="$f${g+.}$g" ;done;echo "$g" )
```

Use `printf %s "$g"` if any of the dotted elements could start with a hyphen.

Comment: That's a neat one-liner!